# Can You Help Me On This Maximum Likelihood Estimation Question Please?

Tags: calculus, statistics

The Question: A random sample of size $n$ is taken from this pdf. 
$f_{Y}(y:θ) = \frac{2y}{θ^{2}}$, $0 \leq y \leq θ$. Find an expression for $θ_{e}$, the maximum likelihood estimator for $θ$.

The Attempt: First of all, if I were to take the first derivative test of this function, I will not get a solution for $θ_{e}$. Secondly, the function being represented is not a uniform pdf so I cannot say the maximum $Y_{i}$, is not the maximum likelihood estimator. I guess I am not sure what to do in this problem. Can you guys give me some hints if you can.

Thank you guys. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Trivially, $\theta_e$ is equal to the max of the sample as your likelihood is a decreasing function of $\theta$ - so you choose the lowest value allowed by your sample.

Comment: So I can say that the maximum likelihood estimator is the maximum value in my sample. Right? I am just not sure how to compute it.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\theta$ is in the support,differentiation is not helpful here.
The likelihood can be written as $L(θ)=(θ^{-2n} \prod 2y_i)I(max(y_{i}),\theta)$, for all $\theta>0$.

Since the likelihood is a decreasing function of $\theta$ for all $\theta \ge max(y_{i})$ and zero otherwise.Hence the maximum occurs at the smallest value of $\theta$, $\theta_{mle}=max(y_{i}).$

Comment: I tried using the method of moments as well and it is kind of different. Could I do that as well?

Comment: Yes you could do what I showed above.This is true since the likelihood is decreasing in $\theta$. the pdf does not have to be uniform to use this technique.